# Requests to rails API have the source IP "11.0.2.1" in that API only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, azure, networking

I recently added logging to a rails API hosted on Azure that logs user IDs and IP addresses that Google Recaptcha v3 has flagged as suspicious (v3 assigns a "trust" score from 0.0 to 1.0 to requests, without showing a conventional captcha challenge). I would eventually like to use Recaptcha v3 to rate-limit suspicious users, but I noticed many flagged requests from the same odd-looking 2 IPs.

I see requests from a variety of users originating from `11.0.2.1` and a smaller subset from `11.0.0.1`. These users seem otherwise legitimate. In our 3rd-party identity provider's logs, I can see those users logged in from normal-looking IPs that match their general locations, but for some reason our API is getting the `11.0.2.1` addresses.

`11.0.2.1` seems to be a default setting on some F5 software and Cisco hardware. Since our Identity Provider seems able to get the correct IP, I am guessing we have a misconfiguration or bug in our rails app. However I'm not able to reproduce this error myself, and see no problems with calling `request.ip` locally or on a test machine.

Am I retrieving IPs wrong or is my API misconfigured somehow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, to get the real client IP address in rails, you should use [`request.remote_ip`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-remote_ip) instead of [`request.ip`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Request.html#method-i-ip). They are different, as below.

[image]

[image]

And the API page for class [`ActionDispatch::RemoteIp`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/RemoteIp.html) shows more details.

> This middleware calculates the IP address of the remote client that is making the request. It does this by checking various headers that could contain the address, and then picking the last-set address that is not on the list of trusted IPs. This follows the precedent set by e.g. [the Tomcat server](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=50453), with [reasoning explained at length](http://blog.gingerlime.com/2012/rails-ip-spoofing-vulnerabilities-and-protection) by @gingerlime. A more detailed explanation of the algorithm is given at [ActionDispatch::RemoteIp::GetIp#calculate_ip](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/RemoteIp/GetIp.html#method-i-calculate_ip).
>
> Some Rack servers concatenate repeated headers, like [HTTP RFC 2616](https://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec4.html#sec4.2) requires. Some Rack servers simply drop preceding headers, and only report the value that was [given in the last header](http://andre.arko.net/2011/12/26/repeated-headers-and-ruby-web-servers). If you are behind multiple proxy servers (like NGINX to HAProxy to Unicorn) then you should test your Rack server to make sure your data is good.
>
> IF YOU DON'T USE A PROXY, THIS MAKES YOU VULNERABLE TO IP SPOOFING. This middleware assumes that there is at least one proxy sitting around and setting headers with the client's remote IP address. If you don't use a proxy, because you are hosted on e.g. Heroku without SSL, any client can claim to have any IP address by setting the X-Forwarded-For header. If you care about that, then you need to explicitly drop or ignore those headers sometime before this middleware runs.

Comment: This looks like the problem I'm seeing (presumably `request.ip` is giving me the default IP of proxies from certain networking tools), thanks a ton. I'll test it out and mark as resolved if things look good.

Comment: So this put me on the right track. I'm using an Azure Web App For Containers, an abstraction that lets me run a Docker image on an easily scalable resource. However after talking to their support, apparently they use a reverse proxy that doesn't pass `x-forwarded-for`, which is the source of the 11.0.0.* requests. So I might need to just switch to a totally different cloud resource to get this working. So your answer is definitely right and would fix it if there was a properly configured proxy, but sadly there isn't.